# How to set "All Except List Below" on IIS relay restriction via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, relay

I need help on how to create a PowerShell script to change the relay restriction on my Datacenter IIS.

By default the radio that is marked is the "Only the list below" and I want to change it to "All except the list below" using PowerShell.

[image]

I already have the code to include the IP "Only the list below" but I need to know how to change the selected radio for the other approach.

Comment: Had to delete my answer, sorry. Can't verify that the option "All except the list below" is enabled. It worked for me on a Windows 2012 machine, but on 2016 and 2019 it failed.

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below script to modify the setting:

```
$iisObject = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(“IIS://localhost/SmtpSvc/1”)
$relays = $iisObject.Properties[“RelayIpList”].Value

[Object[]] $grantByDefault = @()
$grantByDefault += , $true

$relays.GetType().InvokeMember(“GrantByDefault”, $bindingFlags, $null, $relays, $grantByDefault);

$iisObject.Properties[“RelayIpList”].Value = $relays
$iisObject.CommitChanges()
```